# remove what was appended and add other things on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of Li's that wen clicked on will have a class of plSel, When clicked, I want them to have a different video playing and the other videos, clear off

This is how I have it down on my html:

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video id="appendVid" loop muted autoplay poster="assets/one.png" class="fullscreen-bg__video">

    </video>
</div>
```

and later the lis appear like this:

```
 <li id="numb01"></li>
 <li id="numb02"></li>
 <li id="numb03"></li>
 <li id="numb04" class="plSel"></li> //whenclicked
```

and this is how I've laid out my JS so far, the problem is when it gets to be more than one, it just wont work

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  if ($('#numb01').hasClass('plSel')) {
    $('#appendVid').append('<source src="assets/one.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="assets/one.ogv" type="video/ogg">');
});
```

how do i continue it on to remove what was appended and append the next one for each li each video would have something like this appended `<source src="assets/two.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="assets/two.ogv" type="video/ogg">`

thanks for your help

Comment: So you want an opportunity to have more than one video activated by clicks?

Comment: yes basically on click of each li, the video should be activated and the other ones should go away

Comment: It's unclear. Could you edit you post and clean it please ?

Comment: yes i changed it a bit and cleared it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to pair them as you need grammar there. I mean class `one` with `numb01`. It could be better if you keep those naming convention better. In case you still them unmodified, at least you should collect them within a scope. Just like `li` has always `ul` as their parent.

If both video and list have their position in correct order, here I use jQuery [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to find its position, then `show` it and collect its `siblings` element then `hide` them. Then find which video to show by found index, hide its siblings, that's all.

I also showing here on how easier you'll get it if you can store related selector with better naming convention. Example here using `data-` attribute on button to relate target `li` visibility.

```js
$(function () {
  var index = $('.numb .plSel').index()

  $('.fullscreen-bg:eq('+ index +')').show().siblings().hide()
})

$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle]', function () {
  var targetId = $(this).data('toggle')
  targetId = $(targetId)
  var index = targetId.index()

  targetId.show().siblings().hide()
  $('.fullscreen-bg:eq('+ index +')').show().siblings().hide()
})
```

```css
.numb {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.numb > li:not(.plSel) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fullscreen">
  <div class="fullscreen-bg one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg one">
    Three
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="numb">
 <li id="numb01" class="plSel">Numb 1</li>
 <li id="numb02">Numb 2</li>
 <li id="numb03">Numb 3</li>
</ul>

<button type="button" data-toggle="#numb01">Toggle One</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="#numb02">Toggle Two</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="#numb03">Toggle Three</button>
```

Comment: got it to work via modifying this a bit! thanks!! :)  https://jsfiddle.net/z0ma028q/

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted your HTML, but I think this is what you want. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/duuzv372/)

```js
$(document).on("click", ".menu ul li a", function() {
  $(".container > div").eq($(this).parent().attr("id")-1).addClass("plSel");
  $(".container > div").not(".plSel").css("display", "none");
})
```

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.fullscreen-bg {
  float: left;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkblue;
}

li a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.fullscreen-bg:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="1"><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li id="2"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li id="3"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li id="4"><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li id="5"><a href="#">Five</a></li>
    <li id="6"><a href="#">Six</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="fullscreen-bg one">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg two">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg three">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg four">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg five">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
  </div>
  <div class="fullscreen-bg six">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```